# Sharepoint list formatting- contact card image, name and title with hover for more text information (about the person)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am trying to format a list view by tailoring samples from github. I am trying to create a user profile card where you hover over the card and information about the person is shown like a short bio of the person.

The profile card is here:

https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/view-samples/profile-card

Its good as it allows inserting your own image.

The hover feature would be great to take from this one here:

https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/view-samples/horse-crests

This would allow the more information to be highlighted. I am just really struggling to create a hybrid of the two.

If anyone can help, I would really appreciate it. I have spent hours trying to merge the two to create what I need. Many thanks.